# How to disable all location services in parrot os?

Tags: geolocation, location, ip, parrot-os

Is there a way to disable all location services in parrot os?

I don't want any app or anything  to know my location ( including geoclue-2.0 )

- Please give the way without lectures I know the disadvantages ^_^

Answer (score 0):

Well, you safest bet is to disable geoclue, so it won't access your location and won't affect anything else either.

```
sudo systemctl disable geoclue.service
sudo systemctl mask geoclue.service
```

Run these commands as sudo to get the desired result.

Protip: There are many factors to determine a users location, disabling geoclue isn't going to help much. Things such as IP address, MAC address, browser fingerprinting, trackers, etc. are more than enough to find your location.